# How to find absolute path of the parent working directory without needing additional command line parameters

Tags: paths, file-lookup

I have an answer for this, but it's been bugging me that all solutions I could previously find required either `--shell-escape` or (using currfile) `-recorder`, making it pretty much impossible to write a nice, convenient package that people can just use without having to modify their IDEs to use alternative `pdflatex`-parameters, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is, that it is possible to call `kpsewhich` from within tex without `--shell-escape`, which allows getting at the PWD with slightly different syntax, depending on windows or unix/mac.

Unix: `kpsewhich -var-value PWD`

Windows: `kpsewhich -expand-var %CD%` - for some reason, `var-value` doesn't work with `%CD%`.

Now we only need to take care of

1. finding out which OS is being used (using expl3's `\c_sys_platform_str`),
2. catcode hell with respect to the characters in expl3 strings,
3. catcode hell to deal with the `%`-character, and
4. catcode hell with `\`-characters in windows paths.

Here's what I came up with:

```
\begingroup
  \edef\oldpercentcatcode{\the\catcode`\%}
  \catcode`\%=12
  \def\percent{%}
  \catcode`\%=\oldpercentcatcode
  \ExplSyntaxOn
    \edef\windowsstring{\detokenize{windows}}
    \edef\os_string{\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\c_sys_platform_str}}
    \ifx\os_string\windowsstring
      \edef\cmd_string{kpsewhich ~ -expand-var ~ \percent CD\percent}
    \else
      \edef\cmd_string{kpsewhich ~ -var-value ~ PWD}
    \fi
    \expandafter\sys_get_shell:nnN\expandafter{\cmd_string} { } \mainfile_dir
        \tl_trim_spaces:N \mainfile_dir
    \xdef\mainfile_dir{\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\mainfile_dir}}
  \ExplSyntaxOff
\endgroup
```